# This is a small function to delete an object.. i wanted to ask that how instance.get_another_url() works even though instance got deleted?

Tags: django, django-views

```
def post_delete(request,id):

    instance= get_object_or_404(Post , id=id)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request , "Post deleted!")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_another_url())
```

Comment: `instance.delete()` means you delete it *from the database*. But as long as `get_another_url` depends on the attributes of the object, it can generate a URL, so that is not really a problem.

Comment: So when does he instance get deleted out of memory? After making migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `Model.delete()` it will delete the row from the database, however, that doesn't remove your current instance from memory.  In this case `get_another_url` works because you can still access attributes that were cached on the instance.

If you were to get the instance from a QuerySet that used [`.only(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) or [`.defer(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) (which defers fields to be retrieved in a lazier fashion, rather than all the fields on the model being retrieved at once) then you would most likely encounter some error when it attempts to retrieve the remaining fields from the database.

```
queryset = QuerySet.objects.filter().only("one_field")  # Will only retrieve id and one_field column from database
instance = queryset.first()
instance.delete()
instance.another_field  # Raises DatabaseError
```